# Setting up ssh key without a passphrase

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to create an ansible and I want an ssh key specific for the ansible that requires no passphrase (for automation pourposes). Here's what I've done:

```
> ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "ansible"
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\user_name/.ssh/id_ed25519): C:\Users\user_name/.ssh/ansible
```

At the following:

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
```

I left them empty and just pressed enter and
the public/private key files get created.

I copied the public key to the VM I want to connect to and made sure it's there by looking inside the

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But when I try connecting to the VM, with the ansible specific ssh key I just created (which doesn't require a passphrase) it asks me for the password...

```
ssh -i C:\Users\user_name/.ssh/ansible   ip_addr
user_name@ip_addr's password:
```

Now, I believe the password is asking for it's the one of the VM itself, not the ssh key, but I was expecting to ssh inside without having to enter any sort of password. What am I missing?

The host machine is Windows 10, the VM has Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: try copying the public key with `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: ```ssh-copy-id``` doesn't work on windows, but I had found a workaround on another SO question ```cat .\ansible.pub | ssh user@ip_addr_vm "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys```. Which did the job, as I said in my question I can see the public key in the *authorized_keys* file of the VM.

Comment: I use `ssh-copy-id` on Windows with Cygwin, but anyway, you can add `-v` , `-vv`, `-vvv` and so on to the `ssh` command to see why it does not use that public key